# Limit upload speed for MiniO (node.js)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bandwidth, minio

I need set a limit for upload speed for a script that uploads videos to a S3 (MiniO). I tried with *'speed-limiter'* and *'bandwidth-throttle-stream'* and doesn't work.

I want to limit the upload speed to **8MB/s**

(This is my first node.js script)

```
const chokidar = require('chokidar')
const notifier = require('node-notifier')
const Minio = require('minio')

const minio = new Minio.Client({
    endPoint: '${dns-example}',
    port: 9000,
    useSSL: false,
    accessKey: '${user-example}',
    secretKey: '${pass-example}'
})

const metaData = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
  'X-Amz-Meta-Testing': 1234,
  'example': 5678
}

chokidar.watch('/Users/glichester/Movies', {ignoreInitial: true}).on('add', path => {
  notifier.notify({
    title: 'New clip saved',
    message: `Clip: ${path.slice(24)}`,
    icon: 'icon.png',
    sound: true,
    appID: "Clip saver"
  })
  chokidar.watch(path).on('change', file => minio.fPutObject('glichester', path.slice(24), path, metaData, err => {
    notifier.notify({
      title: `Clip uploaded ${err == null ? "correctly" : "fail"}`,
      message: `It's ${err == null ? "uploaded" : "tried to upload"} to the cloud ${path.slice(24)}... ERROR: ${err}`,
      icon: 'icon.png',
      sound: true,
      appID: "Clip saver"
    })
  }))
})
```

This script works.

Comment: Can I ask... _Why_ do you wish to limit this speed?

Comment: This is a script for gamers, so when i make a clip, increases the ping beacause the script eat all the bandwidth. Normal ping: 15ms. Uploading video ping: 300ms - 500ms